# Using SharedPreferences and Editor as members

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have a `Settings` class, that uses `SharedPreferences` to load and save settings. To make it readable, I made the `Editor` and `SharedPreferences` objects members of that class and call on them set read and write settings. However, this doesn't seem to work well.

This is the `Settings` class:

```
public class Settings { 
    protected Context ctx;
    protected SharedPreferences sp;
    protected Editor edit;

    public Settings(Context c) {
         ctx = c;       
         sp = ctx.getSharedPreferences("app_settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         edit = sp.edit();
    }

    public void setString(String name, String value) {
        edit.clear();
        edit.putString(name, value);
        edit.commit();
    }
    public String getString(String name, String def) {
        return sp.getString(name, def);
    }
}
```

And I call like this (from my from `Application` extended `MyApplication`'s `onCreate`:

```
Settings s = new Settings(getApplicationContext());
s.setString("foo", "bar");
```

When I reread that value, I always get the default value:

```
String value = s.getString("foo", "default");
```

Comment: @PANDA no difference. If I use a clean calling, it does work by the way. So I guess I have some other problem somewhere.

Comment: change Editor declaration like SharedPreferences.Editor edit

Comment: @kettu: no difference

Comment: Please check the context you are passing...that might be the problem as you are getting default values...make sure you pass Application context

Comment: I do pass `Application` context. I also implemented `putInt`, which works fine.

Comment: Does `Settings s = new Settings(getApplicationContext());` result in the same behavior?

Comment: You are clearing Editor (edit.clear()) while adding new value. So all previous values are removed.

Comment: Could you post the code how you are reading

Comment: I think the context which you send to Settings doesn't approach to this. Are you sure to send a context of Application? not a basecontext?

Comment: @kettu: it was the `clear()`. I took it from other code I wrote earlier. Apparently that app has a bug ;-). If you make it an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: public abstract SharedPreferences.Editor clear ()
Added in API level 1

Mark in the editor to remove all values from the preferences. Once commit is called, the only remaining preferences will be any that you have defined in this editor.

Note that when committing back to the preferences, the clear is done first, regardless of whether you called clear before or after put methods on this editor.
Returns

    Returns a reference to the same Editor object, so you can chain put calls together.

Comment: yes...its because of clear()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of edit.clear()

change this method

```
public void setString(String name, String value) {
    edit.clear();
    edit.putString(name, value);
    edit.commit();
}
```

as follows

```
public void setString(String name, String value) {

    edit.putString(name, value);
    edit.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
private final String LANGUAGE = "Language";//Key to identify field in sharedPrefrence file.
private final String PREFS_NAME = "SharedPreferenceFile";//Shared Preference file name.

public String getLanguageFromSharedPreference() {
    sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(LANGUAGE, "en");
}

public void setLanguageToSharedPreference(String newlang) {
    sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(LANGUAGE, newlang);
    editor.commit();
}
```